# VB Script / Batch file to Monitor and send mail for Computer/server running processes

Tags: email, batch-file, vbscript, monitor, taskmanager

I am looking solution to monitor process or processes (visible in Task Manager) running in computer/server and on killing of same either manually or itself should generate and alert mail to specified Email IDs specially for particular task process if possible.

Please help me in same, i have tried few options but only able to list process list but not able to generate mailer on killing of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a WMI Event watcher based on the `__InstanceDeletionEvent`, it will tell you when the `notepad.exe` is closed via wscript popup and restart itself if you name it "Notepad_Emailer.vbs"

```
strComputer = "."
Set objSWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!" & "\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objEventSource = objSWbemServices.ExecNotificationQuery( "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent " & "WITHIN 1 " & "WHERE TargetInstance " & "ISA 'Win32_Process' " & "AND TargetInstance.Name = 'notepad.exe'")
Set objEventObject = objEventSource.NextEvent()
set kdshell = createobject("WScript.Shell")
Wscript.Echo "NOTEPAD WAS CLOSED, REPLACE THIS LINE WITH YOUR EMAIL SCRIPT"
kdshell.Run "Notepad_Emailer.vbs",0,false
```

Combine this with your email snippet and you are all set.

Comment: or here is a more advanced powershell version that you could modify.  http://superuser.com/questions/693596/how-to-know-which-service-is-responsible-for-any-exe-running/693601#693601

Comment: thanks for help, but its working as i already tried for listing process, its help full but when trying to integrate the email code in same its stop working, i am not much in vbscripts but still like to play with same in case little more help will be appreciable with email code integration in same.

Comment: Thanks i have done...but could not drop complete code here, as i do not have that much repo as code itself includes few links of microsoft default...rest thanks a ton

Comment: hi knuckle-dragger,
Can we modify code for machine specific user service/process as with different user name same process run simuntaneous on server like for me required for java.exe, its working but when ever the other then my app java.exe get restarted then alert get generated.

Comment: did you try task scheduler

Comment: I can arrange the same using task scheduler, but would be not feasable that much implementations @ production level as per change manamgement process. so please help in same accordingly.

Comment: hi Knucle, Please help